Changing window size for scrapy spider
I am very new to web-scraping and I just watch that 4-hour video tutorial in YouTube.
Recently, I am trying to get data from jobsdb.com, and I always get empty value on some of the fields, what more strange is that I can actually see the data from the browser. After long time of trying, I realise it is because some of the data will be hidden if I make the window size too small, and maybe this is reason why my scrapy spider cannot get those data.
Website I am using now:https://hk.jobsdb.com/data-engineer-jobs
#I can get data of title but not the job_description 
Jobs = response.css('[data-automation="normalJob"]') 

Title = Jobs.css('[data-automation="jobTitle"]::text').get() 
Job_Desc = Jobs.css('[data-automation="jobShortDescription"]::text').get() 

Please tell me if u need the whole code, the code run perfectly and just cannot get some of the data like the Job_Desc.
Since I am not really sure how scrapy get data, maybe just get the html so it ignore the windows size?
So I am thinking of some solution:

Add some code to tell scrapy use a bigger window size
Change the url (maybe add something like ?window-size="1920x1080")
Add some JS using scrapy-splash

Here's all solution I can think of, but they seems not working...

Scrapy is a HTTP client, talking about window sizes makes no sense in its context. Also I don't see jobShortDescription even in the browser.

jobShortDescription will only show the the browser width is less than 1000px, also it is not a class, it is under data-automation, also for some css it will show or disappear with the browser size or when cursor hover on the element, then how can i scrape those element?

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Please share the source code that you' re trying to run, so we can try to reproduce the same error and fix your issue.
